# Can we have variadic concepts before variadic template parameters?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Can we have variadic concepts before variadic template parameters?

I meant, is following legal:

```
template <class, std::size_t> concept Any = true;

template <class> struct n_ary;

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct n_ary<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
  template <Any<Is>... Ls, typename ... Ts>
  void operator()(Ls..., Ts...) {}
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/faPzWbcrP) (accepted only by clang)

Note: Without the extra `Ts`, it is accepted by all compilers [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Yx668ePs).

Comment: @NicolBolas: Currently, concept accepts any type. Idea was to have `operator (T1, T2,.., TN, Ts...)` with fixed `N`. (Concept could be more complex though). I found workaround with only`Ts...` and `requires(sizeof...(Ts) >= N)`, but question remains.

Comment: I think this is ok. It will work if you [manually fill in `Any`](https://godbolt.org/z/q69d1YbPd), and it is equivalent to the parameter pack version.

Comment: So compiler bug (or feature not yet implemented) from gcc/msvc?

Comment: gcc/msvc's implementation of C++ new features has always been ahead of clang, so I suspect this is a compiler bug. But I am not a language lawyer, so this still requires a language lawyer to quote relevant wording :-D

Comment: In fact, you do not expand `Is` by mistake, [msvc/gcc will accept it](https://godbolt.org/z/M833hbWM4). I believe the answer to this question should be clear, but interestingly, clang crashed.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Maybe gcc/msvc tend to be ahead in terms of first releasing new features, but clang is generally the best of them when it comes to standard compliance in language-lawyer corner cases.

Comment: @Jarod42: Sorry, I saw `… Ls` and overlooked the pack *expansion* that was the whole point of that part.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably in violation of [[temp.param] section 14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#14):

> ... A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of the function template or has a default argument ([temp.deduct]). ...

It includes this example:

```cpp
template<class T1 = int, class T2> class B;     // error

// U can be neither deduced from the parameter-type-list nor specified
template<class... T, class... U> void f() { }   // error
template<class... T, class U> void g() { }      // error
```

However, cases like `f(T..., U...)` are currently accepted by compilers, which see one (or both) parameter packs as empty.

By the the example in [section 5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#5) about type constraints,

```cpp
template<C3<int>... T> struct s5;       // associates (C3<T, int> && ...)
```

the syntax in your example should be "functionally equivalent, but not equivalent" to `template<typename... Ls, typename... Ts> requires (Any<Ls,Is> && ...)`. The expansion rules [[temp.variadic]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.variadic#7) require that `Ls` and `Is` have the same size, which is why gcc and MSVC ultimately reject the call in your example. Interestingly, if you use the functionally equivalent syntax, clang does join the other compilers in rejecting it.

Comment: The function template `n_ary<0,1,2>::operator()` arguably doesn’t have a template parameter after a template parameter pack because of substitution of `Is` into its parameter list.

Comment: @DavisHerring: But doesn't that still leave the `Ls` constrained using `Is` as unknown types? As far as I understand, before checking the constraints, the compiler first has to determine what the `Ls` and `Ts` are purely based on their types, which I don't think it can.

Comment: They aren’t known, but it then presumably looks like `template<Any<0> __Ls0,Any<1> __Ls1,Any<2> __Ls2,typename ...Ts>`.  The standard is none too clear on this point: instantiation is barely described at all, and nested templates are hard.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah I see. I'm not sure the standard allows that interpretation, but it's probably how clang does it!